# How to update a value in a database with the value from another database if a condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I want to do the following. I have two datasets. In the example code df1 and df2. I want to update the rows of each patient where the IntDen values are in df1 with the values of df2 if the row with count value in df1 equals the count value in df2. I just can't seem to manage to get the new intden value in df1_updated. I've tried this code and a slight change below which is the furthest I got.

```
# Create sample data frames
df1 <- data.frame(patient = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5)), 
                  measurement = rep(c("Count", "Area", "StdDev", "IntDen", "RawIntDen"), 3), 
                  value1 = 1:15, value2 = 2:16, value3 = 3:17, value4 = 4:18, value5 = 5:19)
df2 <- data.frame(patient = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5)), 
                  measurement = rep(c("Count", "Area", "StdDev", "IntDen", "RawIntDen"), 3), 
                  value1 = c(rep(1,15)), value2 = c(rep(4, 15)), value3 = 5:19, value4 = 6:20, value5 = 7:21, value6 = 8:22)


# Create a copy of df1 to store the updated values
df1_updated <- df1

# Loop over each patient in df1
for (patient in unique(df1$patient)) {
  # Subset df1 and df2 for the current patient
  df1_patient <- df1[df1$patient == patient, ]
  df2_patient <- df2[df2$patient == patient, ]
  
  # Get the row index of the "Count" measurement in df1 and df2
  count_row_idx_df1 <- which(df1_patient$measurement == "Count")
  count_row_idx_df2 <- which(df2_patient$measurement == "Count")
  
  # Get the row index of the "IntDen" measurement in df1 and df2
  intden_row_idx_df1 <- which(df1_patient$measurement == "IntDen")
  intden_row_idx_df2 <- which(df2_patient$measurement == "IntDen")
  
  # Check if the "Count" value in df1 is in df2
  count_value <- df1_patient[count_row_idx_df1, grep("value", names(df1_patient))]
  for(count_value in df2_patient[count_row_idx_df2, grep("value", names(df2_patient))]) {
  if (any(count_value) %in% df2_patient[count_row_idx_df2, grep("value", names(df2_patient))]) {
    # Get the column index of the matching "Count" value in df2
    match_col_idx_df2 <- which(df2_patient[count_row_idx_df2, grep("value", names(df2_patient))] %in% count_value)
    
    # Update the "IntDen" value in df1_updated
    intden_value <- df2_patient[intden_row_idx_df2, match_col_idx_df2]
    df1_updated[intden_row_idx_df1, match_col_idx_df2] <- intden_value
     }
  }
}
```

I've tried the following, which does change some values but for completely the wrong ones.

```
> # Loop over each patient in df1
> for (patient in unique(df1$patient)) {
+   # Subset df1 and df2 for the current patient
+   df1_patient <- df1[df1$patient == patient, ]
+   df2_patient <- df2[df2$patient == patient, ]
+   
+   # Get the row index of the "Count" measurement in df1 and df2
+   count_row_idx_df1 <- which(df1_patient$measurement == "Count")
+   count_row_idx_df2 <- which(df2_patient$measurement == "Count")
+   
+   # Get the row index of the "IntDen" measurement in df1 and df2
+   intden_row_idx_df1 <- which(df1_patient$measurement == "IntDen")
+   intden_row_idx_df2 <- which(df2_patient$measurement == "IntDen")
+   
+   # Check if the "Count" value in df1 is in df2
+   count_value <- df1_patient[count_row_idx_df1, grep("value", names(df1_patient))]
+   for (count_value in df2_patient[count_row_idx_df2, grep("value", names(df2_patient))]) {
+     # Get the column index of the matching "Count" value in df2
+     match_col_idx_df2 <- which(df2_patient[count_row_idx_df2, grep("value", names(df2_patient))] %in% count_value)
+     
+     # Update the "IntDen" value in df1_updated
+     intden_value <- df2_patient[intden_row_idx_df2, match_col_idx_df2]
+     df1_updated[intden_row_idx_df1, match_col_idx_df2] <- intden_value
+   }
+ }
> df1_updated
```

If the could would work, the df1_updated in this example would look like this:

[Example outout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPD3U.png)

Code to generate example output:

```
df1_updated_example <- data.frame(patient = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5)), 
                                         measurement = rep(c("Count", "Area", "StdDev", "IntDen", "RawIntDen"), 3), 
                                         value1 = c(1,2,3,1,5:15), value2 = 2:16, value3 = 3:17, value4 = c(4,5,6,4,8:18), value5 = 5:19)
```

So in this example the changes were only for patient A. The value of the integrated density row for patient A changed from 4 to 1 in the same column (value 1 in this case) as where the value of the row with the count outcome was 1. As this value was also present in df2 for patient A.
The same happens again for patient A in the value4 column. The value changes from 6 to 4 in the integrated density row as the corresponding count row in that column with a value of 4, was also present in df2 in column value2.

I hope what I want to achieve is clear and somebody knows the solution.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your desired output from these data?

Comment: Yes, of course. My apologies.